# Separate membership payment on contribution form with donation

Tags: civimember, contributions

When creating a contribution page with a membership, which is not a price set, the option to:
"Separate Membership Payment" is shown. This creates a transaction transaction for any donations and memberships on the same sign up form.

A separate membership payment will: "Check this box if you are including both Membership Signup/Renewal AND a Contribution Amount section, AND you want the membership fee to be charged separately from any additional contribution amount."

Unfortunately when using a price set, the donation options do not appear on the forms, and the option to separate payments is removed. It doesn't appear possible to separate a contribution with donations into two separate transactions.

How can I keep using a membership price set, but also enable donations on the same form through separate transactions?

Comment: Can you say more about what you want in terms of "separate transactions"?  Is it mandatory that the credit card be charged twice?  Or just that you be able to separate the payments into two separate financial types for reporting purposes?

Comment: It looks like that what you want is not possible. Maybe it is possible with the drupal webform civicrm module.

Answer (score 1):

The separate transaction option is not available with price sets - if you want both you should maybe hire a consultant to develop something.